# Google Maps Embed - Remove Place Card

Tags: google-maps, iframe, hide, google-maps-embed

I'm using the new Google maps embed code (iFrame) to add a small map to my website, but I can't hide the new address box in the top left corner (see image below).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JOVXkra.jpg]

I have generated the map code by clicking the "Share and embed map" option (see image below), but I'm wondering if I need to use the full API to achieve this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xxl25Ga.png]

All of the resources I've found so far just discuss the old embedding version and disabling the information balloon which is not the same, and the only clue I've got is that the HTML class of the box is called "place-card" but searching is still bringing me nothing.

Any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is a more comprehensive discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334042/google-maps-removing-controls

Comment: Super late, but here's another way to remove it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37083353/3130549

Comment: That's great, thanks. If you add the same answer here I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 39):

You can hide all buttons with css. Create a container div width overflow on hidden and the sizes you need. Place the new google maps iframe/embed inside with a largersize. To position the maps iframe use negative marges..

Example with 100% width:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;">
  <iframe 
     src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d39797.07748547086!2d5.46683904751879!3d51.433965676849986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c6d90575ca5e3d%3A0x55989f5f344b006!2sPrins+Hendrikstraat+5!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1392716144537"
     width="100%"
     height="600"
     frameborder="0"
     style="border:0; margin-top: -150px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Make the iframe 300px higher than your container div. 150px to hide below and 150px to hide on top. To hide this 150 on the top of the iframe use:

> margin-top: -150px;

Comment: Seems pretty hacky, but pretty clever too. +1

Comment: do you think this could be seen as an infringement of google's terms? i'm asking this because if you do the same thing to hide the copyright line on the bottom you could get in trouble.

Comment: that's not what i asked, i'm just wondering if hiding the **buttons on the top** couldn't be seen as an infringement like it is when you hide the copyright line.

Comment: The problem with this is it also hides the zoom controls

Comment: @coneybeare you can keep the zoom controlls if you change the css style. Set the margin-left negative (i guess -100px) and the height lower.

Comment: Right, but then you lose any centered pin from showing up in the center.

Comment: @coneybeare you can change the centerpoint in the url from Google when you create the iframe.

Comment: @BoPennings No. Doing longitude and latitude map adjustments taking pixel size and zoom level into consideration is nightmarish at best. Not a valid solution at all.

Comment: Perfect and clever logic. Thumbs up for you!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

1. Go to https://www.maps.ie/coordinates.html to get your Coordinates
2. Go to Google Maps and enter those coordinates (comma separated like this: 33.319663, -111.89780100000002)
3. Click on Share (located on the left)
4. Click on Embed Map
5. Configure the size of map that you want
6. Copy the html

Your iframe will be something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3333.967410377096!2d-111.89998968453055!3d33.31966746342457!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzPCsDE5JzEwLjgiTiAxMTHCsDUzJzUyLjEiVw!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1516690469899" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and was a really great trick if you need to keep all the other map buttons and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove placecard & map controls (map type & zoom icons)

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 350px;">
    <iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  style="border:0; margin-top: -150px;"  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=l&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Walt+Disney+World+Resort&amp;aq=t&amp;sll=28.38545007745952, -81.56377744291994&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=28.38545007745952, -81.56377744291994&amp;z=17&amp;om=0&amp;iwloc=addr&amp;iwd=0&amp;layer=0&amp;output=embed"></iframe></small>
    </div>
```

Note: you can add/remove parameters if you want

https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters