# Remove description bubble from embedded google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, embed

Below is my google maps code which embeds a google map iframe into my website. However I need to know which part of the code gets rid of the description bubble as it is in the way and looks awful.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/embed/v1/vie?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=Fef8HgMdTF8HACGtndVv4fvEAykHADl3VT_YRzGtndVv4fvEAw%3BFf-gHwMdtnoIACG4YnecgIb83ykH1S7ttDnYRzG4YnecgIb83w&amp;q=mildenhall+to+raf+lakenheath&amp;aq=&amp;sll=52.387544,0.494041&amp;sspn=0.099739,0.244446&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=52.378862,0.524008&amp;spn=0.035347,0.068778&amp;t=m&amp;saddr=mildenhall&amp;daddr=raf+lakenheath&amp;output=embed/v1/view"></iframe>
```

'&iwloc=near' no longer works with the new google api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have been looking for the same thing and unless there is an undocumented method, unfortunately it looks like this is currently not possible: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters

Answer (score 1):

This answer :

[Google Maps Embed - Remove Place Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687602/google-maps-embed-remove-place-card)

has a method of using a container div with overflow:hidden and a negative margin on the iframe to chop off the top containing the description bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add :

```
&iwloc=near  in iframe src
```

Used like this:

```
<iframe width="400" scrolling="no" height="300" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&q=so21+1aj&z=10&output=embed&iwloc=near" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: thats what I thought too but this method is now outdated and doesnt work

Comment: I too have the same problem.Any body got the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery I removed the bubble, from actual version of / **place autocomplete** version / google maps, modyfing one original function:

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

// ... the function code, before it's closing

// tag I added 3 lines: //

```
      $("div[class='gm-style-iw']").prev('div').remove(); // bubble
      $("div[class='gm-style-iw']").next('div').remove();  // close button
      $("div[class='gm-style-iw']").remove(); // text
```

});

it is also necessary to attach the jQuery library