# Removing information boxes from google map

Tags: html, css

I have a google map and I want to remove white info boxes (1 and 2 in the image below). I have tried the following css:

```
.place-card {
    display:none
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: please share entire code so can get it sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [How to remove place- cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687602/google-maps-embed-remove-place-card)

```
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;">
  <iframe 
     src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d39797.07748547086!2d5.46683904751879!3d51.433965676849986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c6d90575ca5e3d%3A0x55989f5f344b006!2sPrins+Hendrikstraat+5!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1392716144537"
     width="100%"
     height="600"
     frameborder="0"
     style="border:0; margin-top: -150px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```