# Hide google maps Terrain and Labels option

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

We have a Google map on my company's website and we would like to remove the "Terrain" and "Labels" options that become visible when one hovers over Map and Satellite.

I have looked everywhere for options for doing this but couldn`t find anything. Is there a way to maybe do it through javascript or CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the following option is set: mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            }

Comment: Thank you for the link notchris. I ended up finding a way to do it through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334042/google-maps-removing-controls). You have to use the Google Maps API. Otherwise, use a Google Maps plugin via jQuery that allows additional styling.